# How to stop my network connection on WinXP using batch command?

Tags: networking, connection, command

for example, if I want to stop "lan connection 1" in my control pannel, I usually right click it in my control panel and disable it. Now I want to write a script to disable and enable those connections. How can I do it??

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for you:

`netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled`

put your connection name in place of `"Local Area Connection"`.

More detailed syntax of `netsh`:

> Usage set interface [name = ] IfName
>
> ```
>          [ [admin = ] ENABLED|DISABLED
>            [connect = ] CONNECTED|DISCONNECTED
>            [newname = ] NewName ]
>
>   Sets interface parameters.
>
>   IfName  - the name of the interface
>   admin   - whether the interface should be enabled (non-LAN only).
>   connect - whether to connect the interface (non-LAN only).
>   newname - new name for the interface (LAN only).
>
>   Notes:
>   - At least one option other than the name must be specified.
>   - If connect = CONNECTED is specified, then the interface
>     is automatically enabled even if the admin = DISABLED
>     option is specified.
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I followed your instraction, but I got the folliwng error message:
The synta supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.....

Comment: Might be a minor syntax error. I read that `netsh` syntax varies a little between different versions of Windows. Try `netsh /?` maybe this is little syntax difference.